# How to implement accessibility using keyboard arrows for tabulator (easiest way)

Tags: accessibility, tabulator

I want to implement keyboard navigation for tabulator table.
It should support up, down, left, right arrows and accordingly focus should move between cells and rows.
Basically I want to implement something [like this](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices/examples/grid/dataGrids.html)

So by doing minimum changes how can I achieve this?

Comment: What have you tried? Please edit your question to include what you've tried and where you've gotten stuck.

Answer (score 0):

If the table contains read only data then it is not navigable, only editable cells can have focus in Tabulator.

If you have a look at the [Editors Example](http://tabulator.info/examples/5.1#editable) you can see that if you give a cell focus you can then navigate around the table using the arrow and tab keys

Comment: Thanks Oli for responding!! Yes I know built In support is there for editable table. But I want to Implement It for non-editable tables. For that I need help

Comment: If that is something you would like, please create a [Feature Request](https://github.com/olifolkerd/tabulator/issues/new?assignees=&labels=Suggested+Feature&template=feature_request.md&title=) and i can look at adding a focus navigation mode for the table

Comment: Thanks Oli.. I have created feature https://github.com/olifolkerd/tabulator/issues/3652